# Testing tools and guide for non-technical person

Tags: testing, browser-based

I'm a non-technical guy. I'd like to learn doing automatic testing for front-end. Do you have any recommended browser-based tools for beginners and also a guide that I can follow?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Please note that questions that ask for recommendations would attract [opinion based answers, which are not allowed on the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201994/is-there-a-place-to-ask-opinion-based-questions). However, if you have a specific question for an existing software tool, that is something the community might be able to help with. Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform web test, there are many ways to test,such like **selenium** for web UI automation test, **Postman** for API test, **Jmeter** for web stress http requests test